# Meaning of 32x64 in RISC-V architecture

Tags: arm, riscv

I'm currently studying about computer architecture. I was studying about RISC-V ISA and got few questions.

1. In my book they are handling ARM Instruction Set and RISC-V Instruction Set. But it seems like they are quite similar.(little bit different though) Is RISC-V is variation of ARM instruction set?
2. What does 32 x 64 register file meaning? I tried to find it in google, but what I can see is how to implement 32 x 64 in Verilog stuffs. It seems like it's really basic stuff but I still cannot get it.

Comment: The first is a question for history.  ARM was developed out of ideas from various places, one of which was [Berkely RISC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_RISC).

Comment: 32 x 64 means 32 of 64-bit registers. 32 registers that are each 64-bits wide.

Comment: it is not uncommon to use various sized and shaped srams within a chip design, fifos, store and forward stuff, etc many reasons.  And depending on the processor  design it is also not uncommon to keep the gprs in an sram and that is then called a register file.  32 x 64 as mentioned above means either 64 32 bit registers or more like 32 64 bit registers.

Comment: no risc-v and arm are unrelated.  risc-v bares a close resemblance to mips in its design, arm isnt related.  all instruction sets are as similar as they are different they often have an add with registers a mov, sub, xor, etc.

Comment: It really helped me a lot. Thank you!